# Why does $x^{103} ≡ x^3$ (mod $11$) equal $x^3 ≡ 4$ (mod $11)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why $x^{103} ≡ x^3\pmod{11}$ equal x^3 ≡ 4(mod 11)
I see it at p.69 in 
I understand "x^10 ≡ 1 (mod 11) => x^100 ≡ 1 (mod 11) => x^103 ≡ x^3 (mod 11)" but I do not know "why A answer of x^103 ≡ x^3 (mod 11) is equal a answer of x^3 ≡ 4(mod 11)"

Below is the text, from p. 67 of Silverman's book *A friendly introduction to number theory*.

> [image]

Comment: What is $x$? It can' be 0 or 11, can it?

Comment: It doesn't have to be $x^3\equiv 4\pmod{11}$, this is probably some extra condition of the problem, but you haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. You refer to `p. 69`yet you do not talk of any book. Could add a reference to the book? Also, have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: I write the name of  book in <> but It disappeared. the book is A friendly introduction to Number Theory

Answer (score 1):

If $x^3\equiv 4\pmod{11}$ and $x^{103}\equiv x^3\pmod{11}$, then $x^{103}\equiv4\pmod{11}$

In general, if $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $b\equiv c\pmod{n}$, then $a\equiv c\pmod{n}$

Answer (score 0):

$\!\bmod 11\!:\, $ he is solving $\,x^{\large 103}\equiv 4\ $ by using little Fermat to reduce the exponent from $\,103\,$ to $\,3.\,$ Note $\,0^{\large 103}\!\not\equiv 4,\,$ so $\,x\not\equiv 0,\,$ so little Fermat $\,\Rightarrow\, x^{\large 10}\!\equiv 1.\,$ Raising this to power $10$ using [Congruence Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$$\begin{align}  x^{\large 10}&\equiv 1\ \ \ \ \ {\rm by\ little\ Fermat\ and}\ x\not\equiv 0\\[.3em]
\smash{\overset{(\ \ )^{\Large 10}}\Longrightarrow}\ \ (x^{\large 10})^{\large 10}&\equiv 1^{\large 10}\ \ {\rm by\ the\ Congruence\ Power\ Rule}\\[.3em]
\Longrightarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ x^{\large 100}&\equiv 1\ \ \ \ \ {\rm by\ exponent\ laws}\\[.4em]
\smash{\overset{\large \times\ x^{\Large 3}}\Longrightarrow}\ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#c00}{x^{\large 103}}&\equiv  \color{#c00}{x^{\large 3}}\ \ \ {\rm by\ the\ Congruence\ Product\ Rule}
\end{align}$$

Written more concisely: $\,\ x^{\large 103}\equiv x^{\large 3}(x^{\large 10})^{\large 10}\equiv x^{\large 3}(1^{\large 10})\equiv x^{\large 3}\ $

Thus from $\ \color{#c00}{x^{\large 103}\equiv x^{\large 3}}\ $ we infer $\ \color{#c00}{x^{\large 103}}\equiv 4\iff  \color{#c00}{x^{\large 3}}\equiv 4\,\pmod{\!11}$

**Remark** $ $ The same idea works generally, i.e. if we know that $\, x^{\large n}\equiv 1\,$ then  all exponents on $\,x\,$ can be reduced $\!\bmod n,\,$  i.e. $\,x^{\large k}\equiv x^{\large k\bmod n},\,$ see [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242).